Camera on me and my computer screen all day
I work in marketing for a very small business. I also sit at the front desk and deal with walk ins. Every other employee has an office with a door. Since I am up front the camera that is posted is on me and my computer as well. Unfortunately, there are other employees that have access to all the cameras. Two employees constantly come out asking me if I’m staying busy or to make phone calls anytime I take my eyes off the screen to just give my eyes a break. How do I address this with my head boss?

"Two employees constantly come out asking me [..] anytime I take my eyes off the screen to just give my eyes a break" I'm not outright rejecting your claim, but I am going to question how often this is, and whether you're succumbing to perception bias.

How often is "constantly"?  Every minute, every hour, twice a month?

Address what? The title (camera pointed at you) or what you describe in the body (being bothered by other employees)? What outcome do you want to achieve?

If those employees aren't either your manager or their manager, and you are in fact doing your job, tell them to bugger off and tell management they're harassing you. Creating a hostile work environment, when it isn't their responsibility to monitor you, can get them in serious trouble.

Might lose the vulgar language but I applaud telling them to mind their own business

I'm a firm believer in not making it emphatic unless you must, but if they persist despite being warned that you are finding it annoying and will take it to management if they persist, it may be necessary to hit them with a clue-by-four (sic). Say it quietly and with a smile, admittedly, as you would to a friend who was getting on your nerves, but...

I was always told that individuals who use vulgar language probably are not intelligent enough to use a different word, it’s one thing being around friends and using that language, another to use it at work. I am not saying you’re not intelligent for suggesting a response that uses that type of language of course. Just explaining my viewpoint on the use of that language

Valid point. I rarely resort to it, but there are times when I break that rule for shock value.

@Donald Recent studies have shown the exact opposite.  Swearing is actually a more intelligent use of language. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S038800011400151X?via%3Dihub

@Neil that study was performed on college age women. So all participants have the same general level of education. ITOW It doesn't say what you think it says... A better comparison would be the amount of vulgarities you hear from a doctor with the amount from a ditch digger.

Rolled back to original since the edit changed the tone completely, if OP wants the more diplomatic language, they should update answer.

@Neil - You can show me all the studies you want. A study that only includes 150 people isn't that conclusive.

Folks, debating that study is offtopic here. Let's leave it as "your choice of language affects how people perceive your intelligence, but there are times when", ok? Or take it elsewhere.

If those employees aren't either your manager or their manager, aren't they losing their time - more than the time you may be losing - by looking at you?


Two employees constantly come out asking me if I’m staying busy or to make phone calls anytime I take my eyes off the screen to just give my eyes a break. How do I address this with my head boss?

Is it possible that the "are you keeping busy?" is just caring small talk with a new employee (as opposed to an insinuation that you are idling)?
And what is the nature of the phone calls you are being asked to make? Are they clearly within your remit and not theirs?
And are you positive that their approaches are timed with your pauses so as to imply monitoring by camera (i.e. given your overall pattern of working and pausing, the number and precision of their approaches could not be random)?
If they have a queue of phone calls for you to make, it's possible they are looking at the camera to find what they think is an opportune time to ask, without considering your overall workload.
I'd suggest broaching the issue with your manager, that not only are you finding that every time you pause for breath that these colleagues are approaching you with an additional task, but also that the general sense of being constantly watched by others is creating unease, and ask him what he thinks about the situation.
Depending on the frequency and urgency of the requests, and the apparent distribution of duties, you might also want to ask whether they can handle the calls themselves. You might also want to say you are busy with another list of work, being prepared to defend your right to take breaks without that implying that you have additional capacity to help others.

The camera(s) are likely for safety, since your desk is up front.
If management wanted to spy on you they could use a keylogger. That would give them a much more reliable and easier way to track your productivity.
Has you manager given you specific expectations for productivity? Ensure that you are working within that range if possible.
Regardless, be polite to these people, but let them know that you've got it covered. That the reminders are not needed nor helpful. Even if they are managers.
Because you are a person not a robot, you shouldn't be treated this way. If a manager would need to remind you more than two or three times, they should have retrained or fired you. This ongoing prodding is torture.
This next suggestion I don't make lightly. Unless you see some path for career growth, consider moving on. Is there a long-term future at this job?

I'd be polite the first three times. After that, unless it's clearly someone trying to make friendly conversation and doing it badly, it's "unless you're in my management chain, get out of my face or I report this. "

Yep, I am a big fan of Hanlon's Razor. I've seen it in action too many times.

Cameras are commonly installed for safety reasons, but it's not that rare for them to be misused for people's own benefit. And many people wouldn't be tech-savvy enough to install or monitor a keylogger. But my first suspicion would be that there's some cherry picking or misattribution going on: it might be that the coworkers coming by are coincidental or that it has nothing to do with the camera (e.g. they were just walking past or they have line-of-sight of you from their desk). But that doesn't really change how to deal with the situation.
